# Embedded YouTube Videos Don't Load in Chrome or Safari

Tags: asp.net, api, youtube

I've written a page in ASP.NET which displays a GridView, populated from a YouTube playlist, showing a list of videos in that playlist, with each video in its own row.  Users can click on the thumbnail to have the video open in a ModalPopup Panel and start playing automatically.

This works perfectly well in Internet Explorer 10 and Firefox, but not in Chrome or Safari.  In the latter two browsers, rather than the video loading, there's just a big blank space where the video should be, and nothing happens.  I'm hoping somebody can help me work out why.

My code is posted below.  I should point out that I'm completely new to working with the YouTube API and, having read lots of websites about it I'm pretty certain that what I've written here is not standard!  I've tried to change it to use iFrames and to understand the API better to make my JavaScript more like that I see quoted in YouTube API tutorials, but it never seems to work, whereas what I've written does.  So I'm using the "if it ain't broken..." approach.  But if somebody has the time and inclination to tell me how to rewrite this in a more correct way that'd be amazing.  If not, just some help getting the videos to load in Chrome and Safari would be much appreciated.

```
<%--Javascript--%>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var jsvideoid

    function play() {
        var ytplayer = document.getElementById('ytplayer');
        if (ytplayer) {
            ytplayer.playVideo();
        }
    }
    function stop() {
        var ytplayer = document.getElementById('ytplayer');
        if (ytplayer) {
            ytplayer.stopVideo();
        }
    }
    function loadVideo(id, startSeconds) {
        var ytplayer = document.getElementById('ytplayer');
        if (ytplayer) {
            ytplayer.loadVideoById(id, startSeconds);
        }
    }
    function unloadVideo() {
        var ytplayer = document.getElementById('ytplayer');
        if (ytplayer) {
            ytplayer.destroy();
        }
    }
</script> 

<asp:button ID="btnWatch" runat="server" Text="Watch" Height="30px" style="display:none" />
<div id="plVideo" runat="server" class="modalPopup" >
    <embed id="ytplayer" width="640" height="480" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" style="" name="ytplayer"
        src='http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&version=3&modestbranding=1&rel=0&theme=light&playerapiid=ytplayer' >
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnCloseVideo" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClientClick="stop()" />
</div>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpVideo" runat="server" PopupControlID="plVideo" TargetControlID="btnWatch" CancelControlID="btnCloseVideo" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" ClientIDMode="Static" >
<Animations>
        <OnShown>
            <Parallel Duration="2" Fps="30">
                <FadeIn Duration=".5" Fps="30" />
                <ScriptAction Script="loadVideo(jsvideoid,0)" />
            </Parallel>
        </OnShown>
        <OnHiding>
            <Parallel Duration="2" Fps="30">
                <FadeOut Duration=".5" Fps="30" />
                <ScriptAction Script="unloadVideo()" />
            </Parallel>
        </OnHiding>
    </Animations>
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>


<asp:GridView ID="gvPlaylist" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EnableViewState="false" ShowHeader="false" BorderStyle="none" CssClass="playlistgrid" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="thumbnail">
            <ItemTemplate>                               
                <img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/<%# Eval("videoId") %>/0.jpg' width="240" height="180" 
                    onclick="$find('<%=mpVideo.ClientID%>').show();jsvideoid='<%# Eval("videoId")%>';" style="cursor:pointer;" />           
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="description" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <label class="title" style="cursor:pointer;"><%# Eval("title") %></label><br />
                <b>Duration: </b><%# TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Eval("duration")).ToString%>       
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="xmlPlaylist" runat="server" TransformFile="PlaylistTransform.xslt" >
</asp:XmlDataSource>
```

P.S. While you're here, the unloadVideo function doesn't seem to work either. When a user watches one video, then clicks on the thumbnail of another to watch that one, the ModalPopup displays, showing the stopped instance of the previous video for a moment before loading the requested video.  No doubt this is also a result of the strange way I've written this.

Comment: Have you checked the Console in Chrome / Safari ? Are there any errors ? Also, check IE and Firefox console to make sure they don't display a Warning that could lead to an error in Webkit.

Comment: do you have ScriptManager or ToolkitScriptManager?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your embedded video url into `html5` by appending `?html5=1`  at last of your video url

Answer (score 0):

Chrome or Safari is a [Webkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) browsers and sometimes behavior different from IE\FF.

Please try to add to your `.modalBackground` css the following line:

```
.modalBackground
{
   ...
   z-index:10000;
   ...
}
```

and make sure your are using ToolkitScriptManager rather then using ScriptManager.